# $split and return the first element of an array of object as a new object to main collection in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I have an collection which contains many objects. I need to create a new Object in main from existing Object's data and add reference id to the existing. please help.

```
{
        "_id": "officeLocation",
        "data": [
            {
             "_id": ObjectId("2233),
             "key": "APAC - ANZ" 
             "value": "APAC - ANZ" 
            },
            {
             "_id": ObjectId("21323),
             "key": "APAC - Japan" 
             "value": "APAC - Japan" 
            },
            {
             "_id": ObjectId("2221233),
             "key": "EMEA - CE - Benelux - Brussels" 
             "value": "EMEA - CE - Benelux - Brussels" 
            },
            {
             "_id": ObjectId("2221233),
             "key": "EMEA - CE - Benelux - London" 
             "value": "EMEA - CE - Benelux - London" 
            },
           ]
     }
```

like this I need to split the first part of the key value and make new Object added to the collection called region and it's id to the existing officeLocation as a reference id.

### Expected result:

```
{
        "_id": regions,
        "data" [
            {
              "_id" : ObjecteId(123),
              "key" : APAC
              "value": APAC
            },
            {
              "_id" : ObjectId(1234),
              "key" : EMEA
              "value": EMEA
            }
    
         ]
      },
      {
       "_id": "officeLocation",
       "data": [
            {
             "_id": ObjectId("2233),
             "key": "APAC - ANZ" 
             "value": "APAC - ANZ" 
             "referenceId" : ObjectId(123)
            },
            {
             "_id": ObjectId("21323),
             "key": "APAC - Japan" 
             "value": "APAC - Japan",
             "referenceId" : ObjectId(123) 
            },
            {
             "_id": ObjectId("2221233),
             "key": "EMEA - CE - Benelux - Brussels" 
             "value": "EMEA - CE - Benelux - Brussels",
             "referenceId" : ObjectId(1234)
            },
            {
             "_id": ObjectId("2221233),
             "key": "EMEA - CE - Benelux - London" 
             "value": "EMEA - CE - Benelux - London",
             "referenceId" : ObjectId(1234)
            },
           ]
      }
```

Need to use regular expression to split first - to take out the correct region from the key using mongodb query.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `$split` with ' - ' as delimiter and `$first` to get the region.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "officeLocation"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "region": {
        "$first": {
          "$split": [
            "$data.key",
            " - "
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "regions",
      "regions": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "_id": new ObjectId(),
          "key": "$region",
          "value": "$region"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mgm8-NDniOS)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you also please help on how to update the auto created regions id to respective office location objects? Is it possible to alter existing collection with newly created ids?

Comment: @user3741852 actually your example looks weird to me. I think you want to store them in different collections instead of putting all entries into a single document, is it true? If they are stored as individual documents, `_id` can be automatically generated

Comment: No I want to store them in same collection and update the reference id's to respective office locations. We need insert and update query as well with this aggregate query. any suggestion pls?

Comment: @user3741852 updated the answer. Just adding 1 line of `new ObjectId()`. That javascript syntax shows error in playground but it should be working fine in mongo shell. Also, please be aware of [MongoDB 16MB single document size](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size) if you are expecting to stuff a lot of entries into a single document.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ray. Any idea on how to update the existing officeLocations with newly created regions ObjectId as a reference Id? Means we are trying to link the officelocations with respective regions. Please refer the expected result.

Comment: @user3741852 I don't see any point to link the id given your current structure. You cannot use `$lookup` to link up through the reference id anyway. You might require a lot of application level processing to retrieve the linkage if needed. You can still do something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HRzqMZVQ5Zv), but I am highly skeptical about it's maintainability and readability.

Comment: I understand your point but I am in a situation to use the data as it is and can't go for new collection for reference. Thank a lot for your help @ray.